Is there any option to return column/row value in pandas instead of printing

Hi, Above is my data frame I want to execute .csh launch for given machine, is there any way to iterate and execute .csh instead of printing value using iterrows.
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
     print(launch.iloc[index])


probably something like subprocess.call(['csh', row['launch'], row['Machine ID']]) although it's unclear exactly where the Machine ID should occur.

@mozway Thanks this worked, Also If I want to run .cshrc source or alias what should be command subprocess?

Nor sure, but once you find this out, just craft the subprocess call to add the required parameters.
